# Clone directive element keeping scope and everything attached to it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inside the link function of a directive I am cloning the passed-in element:

```
var original=element.clone(true);
```

I do some DOM changes and later on I want to reset everything, that is restore element to its original form.

Something like: `element.replaceWith(original);` fails.
How can this be done? Should I `$compile(original)(scope)`?

Thanks.

Comment: `element.replaceWith($compile(original.html()(scope))` will work, but does it accomplish what you're looking for? If not, can you provide some more code to show why not?

Comment: OK, I'll try that. I think you can compile DOM elements as well.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, you will have issues with recursive looping (try it and you'll see). There is a way you could potentially get around that too, but you might as well first try compiling the html to see if it does what you want first.

Comment: Thank you. [extra chars]